# clear jQuery array after click

Tags: jquery, arrays

I modified a jQuery script to show a customized layer instead of a modal when clicking on external links.  I have the link sitting in an array until the user clicks "OK" or "Cancel" and gets redirected.  The problem happens if I click another link on the page, then every external link I clicked on loads up in separate tabs.  That being said, I can't figure out how to clear the array after clicking "OK" or "Cancel".

```
$('a[href^="http"]').not('a[href^="{{ shop.url }}"]').click(function(e) {
    var external = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#leaving').toggle('slow');

    $('#linkGo').click(function() {
        $('#leaving').fadeOut(500);
        window.open(window.open.location = external);
    });

    $('#linkCancel').click(function() {
        $('#leaving').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: `.not('a[href^="{{ shop.url }}"]')` - I'm willing to bet Angular isn't working with that. If you're using `ng-href` you can do `:not('a[ng-href]')`

Comment: @tymeJV Why do you think it's Angular? Could as well be [tag:twig].

Comment: a) There is no such thing as a "jQuery array" b) There is no array access whatsoever in the code you've provided

Comment: @connexo -- Ahh yeah - I just always assume `{{}}` is Angular :\ - either way - I bet the interp is screwing it up

Comment: @Jamiec Sorry if my terminology is off.  I assumed it was making an array of links under "external" (as it is loading tabs for all clicked on external links when i click on 1).

Comment: @connexo tried your suggestion, still getting the same problem

Comment: no `external` is just the (string) value of the `href` attribute of the link you're clicking on. a `console.log(external)` will confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

so...i found a workaround.  once i specified a window name (not "_blank") for the window.open command it worked fine.  if there's a different (or better) fix for this let me know.

```
$('#linkGo').click(function() {
    $('#leaving').fadeOut(500);
    window.open(window.open.location = external , "windowName");
});
```